# How to convert python dataframe to nested dictionary based on column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID': ['0','1'], 'col1': [0.73, 0.58], 'col2': [0.51, 0.93], 'Type': ['mean', 'mean'] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID': ['0','1'], 'col1': [0.44, 0.49], 'col2': [0.50, 0.24], 'Type': ['std', 'std'] })
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

[image]

I need to convert to nested dictionary like

```
mydict = {0: {'col1': {'mean': 0.73, 'std': 0.44}, 'col2': {'mean': 0.51, 'std': 0.5}},
 1: {'col1': {'mean': 0.58, 'std': 0.49}, 'col2': {'mean': 0.93, 'std': 0.24}}}
```

[image]

where 'ID' as key, column names as nested key and 'Type' as nested keys and column values as values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for `MultiIndex DataFrame` and then convert to nested dict:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).pivot('Type', 'ID')

d = {level: df.xs(level, axis=1, level=1).to_dict() for level in df.columns.levels[1]}
print (d)
{'0': {'col1': {'mean': 0.73, 'std': 0.44}, 
       'col2': {'mean': 0.51, 'std': 0.5}}, 
 '1': {'col1': {'mean': 0.58, 'std': 0.49}, 
       'col2': {'mean': 0.93, 'std': 0.24}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(df1.drop(columns = 'Type').melt('ID', value_name='mean')
    .merge(df2.drop(columns='Type').melt('ID', value_name='std'))
    .assign(c = lambda x:x[['mean', 'std']].to_dict('records'))
    .pivot('variable','ID', 'c').to_dict())

{'0': {'col1': {'mean': 0.73, 'std': 0.44},
  'col2': {'mean': 0.51, 'std': 0.5}},
 '1': {'col1': {'mean': 0.58, 'std': 0.49},
  'col2': {'mean': 0.93, 'std': 0.24}}}
```